# Undefined Variable on session

Tags: php, session

I got an error from this and `$datereportal_newformat` doesn't show any data.
I start with:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<?php
$datereportal_newformat = $_SESSION['datereportalrl'];
$objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","13950") or die("Error Connect to Database");
$objDB = mysql_select_db("projectwebp");
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM alcohol_report WHERE AL_Date = '$datereportal_newformat'";
echo $strSQL;
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL) or die ("Error Query [".$strSQL."]");
?>
```

I have no idea what's going on

EDIT :

Well, i have beginner for coding so i really have understand what's going on ...
i cant post the entire code but i start declaring variable with this ..

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['button'])){
$dayal = $_POST['select'];
$monthal = $_POST['select2'];
$yearal = $_POST['select3'];
$dateReportal = "$yearal-$monthal-$dayal";
$datereportal_time = strtotime($dateReportal);
$datereportal_newformat = date('Y-m-d',$datereportal_time);
$_SESSION['datereportalrl'] = $datereportal_newformat;
}
..
..
?>
```

I want to comparing to the AL_Date in database in another page for use WHERE clause but, they give blank for $datereportal_newformat;

Sorry for all the trouble, My place still learning about the ordinary SQL Language

Comment: Please post the exact error message!

Comment: DON'T USE the `mysql_*` functions anymore, as they are deprecated. You are very vulnerable for SQL injection.

Comment: Also, it is always advisable to create a non-root user for your database so when any credentials are compromised, not the entire database will be compromised.

Comment: Sorry the full error message is : Undifined variable : datereportal_newformat in line 33

Comment: Then check what's in the session variable!

Answer (score 1):

try to var_dump() your session in this file, there's probably problem in declaring the variable
and also use **non-deprecated version of mysql_***, use mysqli instead.

It would be better if you paste the whole file, so we can see the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you have a undefined error on $_SESSION['datereportalrl'], then $datereportal_newformat is empty, neither are being assigned here. Your problem is where you set value to your session.

Answer (score 0):

just do this-

```
print_r($_SESSION)
```

and if it's print data for $_SESSION['datereportalrl'], then there is some error in your mysql query!
otherwise set your session correctly